# Run Lua in Notepad++ using cmd.exe

Tags: lua, notepad++

I run Lua in Notepad++ using the following and it works:

`"C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\lua.exe" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`

Now I want to run Lua scripts in Notepad++ using a Command Prompt, as seen below:

[image]

I want to achieve this from Notepad++.

Comment: `start "" cmd.exe /K "C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\lua.exe" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`

Comment: Egor, this exact command doesnt work: http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2018/11/10/0011/1313/742689/89/192fd482f9.png

Comment: Try to remove leading `start "" `

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running it on CMD or Notepad, you should try using **[IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)**, with the plugin **[EmmyLua](https://github.com/EmmyLua/IntelliJ-EmmyLua)**.

It is very simple to setup.

[How IntelliJ looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FX5mL.gif)